# SAS says data contains no columns when using linear regression

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and am having issues with using Linear Regression.

I loaded a CSV file and then in **Tasks and Utilities > Tasks > Statistics > Linear Regression** I selected **WORK.BP** (BP = filename) for my data. When I try to select my dependent variable SAS says "No columns are available."

The CVS file appears to have loaded correctly and has 2 columns so I can't figure out what the issue is.

Thanks for the help.

This is the code I used for loading the file:

```
data BP;
infile '/folders/myfolders/BP.csv' dlm =',' firstobs=2;
input BP  $Pressure$;
run;
```

[And this is what the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsUqW.png)

Comment: Why did you read them as character variables if you want to use them in a regression?

Comment: Character variables cannot be used for regression, you need numeric. I would expect the log to have more than the error you're indicating however.

Answer (score 0):

By running your code. you import the .csv file with the 'PRESSURE' variable as character variable; in a linear regression model, you need to have all varaible as *_numeric_*.

In order to do this, I suggest to use the `PROC IMPORT` to import a .csf format file, instead of a `DATA` step  with an `INPUT` statement.

In your case, you shold follows those steps:

1. Define the path where the .csv file is located:

   %let path = *the_folder_path_where_the_csv_file_is_located* ;
2. Define the number of rows from which start your data (by including the labels/variables names in the count):

   %let datarow = 2;
3. Import the .csv file, here named 'BP', as follows:

   proc import datafile="&path.\BP.csv"

   out=BP
   dbms=csv
        replace;
        delimiter=",";
        datarow=&datarow.;
        getnames=YES;

   run;

I assumed that the file you want as output has to be called BP too (you'll find it in the work library!) and that the delimiter is the colon.

Hope this helps!